# SSL connection error in production mode rails 3.2.3 thin server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https

I have

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

in my environment/production.rb file so as to make every request sequre with ssl and https.

I came to know that SSL can't be enabled in development mode. So, I started my thin web server in production mode and when I went to

```
https://127.0.0.1:3000
```

it's the same as the development mode(SSL connection error). Tried almost all the links of first 6 pages fetched by google. Anybody have solution to my problem??

P.S. I'm working on windows and I have client authentication certificate.

Comment: Where do you have that error, in browser or logs? If in logs post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you described is related to using a self-signed certificate.
SSL certificates relies on a chain of trust, where the root CA's (Certification Authority) are at the top.
To understand more how it works, the [Wikipedia entry on SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Layer) provide a good insight. For Self-Signed certificates there's also an entry at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate).

To solve you issue you can have a self-signed certificate (be aware of the security issues), but your users will be always prompted for an action.
Another option is to apply for a certificate on [CertCA](http://www.cacert.org/) since some Linux distributions have them on root CA's.
The last and most reliable option is to acquire a certificate.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Fidalgo. Found that yesterday. It seems that I have to buy SSL certificate.